# For which $a$ is the matrix negative definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the number of integer numbers of $a$ such that the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}-1& 0 & 5 \\ 0 & a-50 & 0 \\ 5 & 0 & 6-a\end{pmatrix}$$ is negative definite.

For that, the eigenvalues must be negative, right?

I calculated the eigenvalues using Wolfram and we get [these](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-1%2C%200%20%2C%205%20%7D%2C%7B%200%20%2C%20a-50%20%2C%200%20%7D%2C%7B%205%20%2C%200%20%2C%206-a%7D%7D%20eigenvalues).

So all these have to be negative and we get a system of inequalities :

$$a-50<0 \\ \frac{1}{2}\left (-\sqrt{a^2-14a+149}-a+5\right ) <0 \\ \frac{1}{2}\left (\sqrt{a^2-14a+149}-a+5 \right )<0$$ So we get from the first $a<50$, from the second $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and from the last one $a>31$.

So the integer values for $a$ are from $32$ to $49$, so there are $49-32+1=18$ values, right?

Comment: I think it is right. But I also think that [Sylvester Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) would be easier here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but it could be slightly simpler: with the help of the [rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) or by other means, it's easy to find the characteristic polynomial is:

$$(\lambda-a+50)(\lambda^2+(a-5)\lambda+a-31)$$

The eigenvalues must all be negative, so, for the first factor, that means $a<50$. For the second factor, instead of computing the roots, note that the sum of the roots must be negative, while the product of the roots must be positive. With [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), that means $a>31$ and $a>5$. So the condition is indeed $31<a<50$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)